# String error - how to fix?

Tags: android, string

Any help i get this error when, I run my program
**Text view has already been  defined in this folder **

```
<resources>
<string name="google_maps_Api_Key">AIzaSyB4RYfDdBxiWPS2eU5j_ehgcQD122asg0E</string>
<string name="app_name">GoogleMapsGooglePlaces</string>
<string name="map">MAP</string>
<string name="mape">Map</string>
<string name="RequestPermision" />
<string name="DenailMessage" />
<string name="ReciveLocation" />
<string name="RateDesc" />
<string name="new_message_notification_title_template" />
<string name="UpdateMsg" />
<string name="enter_your_phone_number">ENTER YOUR PHONE NUMBER</string>
<string name="enter_your_string_smssend">Enter your @string/smsSend</string>
<string name="number" />
<string name="message" />
<string name="send" />
<string name="enter_your_phone_numbernumber" />
<string name="textview">TextView</string>
<string name="sendsms">Send</string>
<string name="textview">TextView</string>
<string name="enter_your_message">Enter your message</string>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at all the listed strings, you defined `<string name="textview">TextView</string>` twice near the bottom.
You can only have one unique string name in the strings resources for Android so just remove one of those lines to fix the error.